# Output of array as comma separated BASH

Tags: json, bash, rest

I'm trying to pull variables from an API in json format and then put them back together with one variable changed and fire them back as a put.

Only issue is that every value has quote marks in it and must go back to the API separated by commas only.

example of what it should see with redacted information, variables inside the **'s:

```
curl -skv -u redacted:redacted -H Content-Type: application/json -X PUT -d'{properties:{basic:{request_rules:[**"/(req) testrule","/test-body","/(req) test - Admin","test-Caching"**]}}}' https://x.x.x.x:9070/api/tm/1.0/config/active/vservers/xxx-xx
```

Obviously if I fire them as a plain array I get spaces instead of commas. However I tried outputting it as a plain string

```
longstr=$(echo ${valuez[@]})
output=$(echo $longstr |sed -e 's/" /",/g')
```

And due to the way bash is interpreted it seems to either interpret the quotes wrong or something else. I guess it might well be the single ticks encapsulating after the PUT -d as well but I'm not sure how I can throw a variable into something that has single ticks.

If I put the raw data in manually it works so it's either the way the variable is being sent or the single ticks. I don't get an error and when I echo the line out it looks perfect.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please show same sample value of `valuez[@]` ?

Comment: "/(req) testrule" "/test-body" "/(req) test - Admin","test-Caching"

Comment: so the output should be `"/(req) testrule","/test-body","/(req) test - Admin","test-Caching"`, but there is a `,` in valuez[@] already, and made the trouble?

Comment: Sorry, no there isn't I copied it from the above. It's blank between the otputs but I've had to redact the content

Comment: in short, the array is "thing" "other thing" "thing again". Basically when i feed the array into a variable using the sed it works fine. Even if there were a comma there it would still work as the sed only replaces the spaces after quote marks

Comment: I provide an answer, please check if it can help you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
valuez=( "/(req) testrule" "/test-body" "/(req) test - Admin" "test-Caching" )

# Temporarily set IFS to some character which is known not to appear in the array.

oifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\014'

# Flatten the array with the * expansion giving a string containing the array's elements separated by the first character of $IFS.

d_arg="${valuez[*]}"
IFS=$oifs

# If necessary, quote or escape embedded quotation marks.  (Implementation-specific, using doubled double quotes as an example.)
d_arg="${d_arg//\"/\"\"}"

# Substitute the known-to-be-absent character for the desired quote+separator+quote.

d_arg="${d_arg//$'\014'/\",\"}"

# Prepend and append quotes.

d_arg="\"$d_arg\""

# insert the prepared arg into the final string.

d_arg="{properties:{basic:{request_rules:[${d_arg}]}}}"

curl ... -d"$d_arg" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have gnu awk with version 4 and above, which support FPAT

```
output=$(echo $longstr |awk '$1=$1' FPAT="(\"[^\"]+\")" OFS=",")
```

#### Explanation

- FPAT #
  This is a regular expression (as a string) that tells gawk to create the fields based on text that matches the regular expression. Assigning a value to FPAT overrides the use of FS and FIELDWIDTHS for field splitting. See Splitting By Content, for more information.
  If gawk is in compatibility mode (see Options), then FPAT has no special meaning, and field-splitting operations occur based exclusively on the value of FS.

Comment: {"error_id":"json.parse_error","error_text":"Invalid JSON data: Hash key was not quoted"} do you think it might be the single quotes? Like I say, when I put the raw data in it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
valuez=( "/(req) testrule" "/test-body" "/(req) test - Admin" "test-Caching" )
csv="" sep=""
for v in "${valuez[@]}"; do csv+="$sep\"$v\""; sep=,; done 
echo "$csv"
```

```
"/(req) testrule","/test-body","/(req) test - Admin","test-Caching"
```

If it's something you need to do repeatedly, but it into a function:

```
toCSV () { 
    local csv sep val
    for val; do
        csv+="$sep\"$val\""
        sep=,
    done
    echo "$csv"
}

csv=$(toCSV "${valuez[@]}")
```